# Is it possible to display each Author's Books in a single row with a single SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

First, I apologize if the question isn't worded the best. I'm very new to SQL and unsure how to phrase it using the correct verbiage. Please see the details below to help extrapolate what I'm looking for:

I have an Authors table with a primary key of Id, as well as two other columns: Name and Age.

I also have a Books table with a primary key of Id, as well as other columns: Title, Price, Pages, and Genre.

And I've learned that a many-to-many relationship means I should have an intermediary table that pairs those relationships using the keys from the other tables. So I have an AuthorsBooks table with a primary key of Id (probably not needed), as well as these columns: AuthorId and BookId.

My goal is to produce one result/table that displays each Author only once, with all of their titles listed in the columns after. Is this even possible since some Authors may have more Books than others?

Here is what I have right now, as well as the result I'm getting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
        ,Title

FROM [dbo].[AuthorsBooks]
JOIN dbo.Authors
    ON AuthorId = Authors.Id
JOIN dbo.Books
    ON BookId = Books.Id
```

Which produces something like this:

```
Author1 Book1
Author1 Book2
Author1 Book5
Author2 Book3
Author2 Book4
Author3 Book4
Author3 Book5
```

But I want something like this:

```
Author1 Book1 Book2 Book5
Author2 Book3 Book4
Author3 Book4 Book5
```

Is this even possible? It's fine if it needs to fill in some NULLs (in the case where the last column doesn't have an entry for an author that doesn't have enough books to match the rows above/below it). I've tried GROUP BY clauses, but I keep getting errors and can't find an aggregate function that would work in this case since they aren't numbers.

As a beginner, a simpler solution would be best, but if there is no "simple" solution, something workable that helps me conceptualize how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    ,(
        SELECT DISTINCT Title + ' '
        FROM [dbo].[AuthorsBooks] ab
        JOIN dbo.Authors a ON ab.AuthorId = a.Id
        JOIN dbo.Books b ON ab.BookId = b.Id
        WHERE ab.authorid = ab1.authorid
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS TITLE
FROM [dbo].[AuthorsBooks] ab1
JOIN dbo.Authors a1 ON ab1.AuthorId = a1.Id
JOIN dbo.Books b1 ON ab1.BookId = b1.Id
```

Comment: This is nice, and might be workable, but is there any way to have each title into it's own column? It seems like this query is basically a concatenation.